# Trying to connect iPad to iPhone hotspot. It pulls up a blank page “captive.apple.com” that never loads

Tags: iphone, ipad, network, wifi, tethering

So I was trying to connect my iPad to my iPhone’s hotspot. It does connect, but as soon as the connection appears to be established, it pulls up a blank page with the URL “captive.apple.com”. This never loads and the connection has no internet.

What do I do?

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252074561